# How to print a plot made by matplotlib on scale like cm?

Tags: python

I want to create a plot of a graph using matplotlib in python. Now I want to print that out on paper but on scale which means that for example each unit on paper is one cm. How can I do this?

I already created my plot program but I don't see usefull options in the plot window.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the plot size to be based on 1 plot unit = 1 cm of display or do you mean you have data to plot which utilizes some dimension other than 1 cm/unit and you need to adjust the data so it conforms to 1 unit/cm

Comment: I want to plot it based on 1cm unit and print that on paper where 1cm unit is also utilized.

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib has `figsize()` available. Unfortunately matplotlib works with inches. Thats why you need to convert your cm values to inches first. Here is an example:

```
cm = 1/2.54  # centimeters in inches
plt.subplots(figsize=(15*cm, 5*cm))
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, '15cm x 5cm', **text_kwargs)
plt.show()
```

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_size_units.html

Comment: But I don't see a difference in the results. If I make it with and without the conversion the picture looks the same which means the window size is the same and also the ratio of the axis are the same.